# Redirect STDOUT of cronjobs

Tags: command-line, cron, mail

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual private server.

There are a few cronjobs defined:

```
00 03 * * * cd /root && ./backupJob.sh
00 04 * * * sudo -u www-data php /var/www/dir/htdocs/bin/indexer.php
00 05 * * * cd /root && ./cleanUpUploadedFilesJob.sh
```

Now the sysadmin receives an email for every cronjob that's executed, even on success. Note that I have a postfix running on the same machine and there is no `MAILTO=""` in the crontab.

The goal is to only receive an email when the script has an exit value other than 0.

If I add `1>/dev/null` to every line, will my standard out be redirected? Will the behavior for standard error stay the same otherwise?

Comment: Why don't you just change them to `command || emailAdmin.sh` where `emailAdmin.sh` is a script that send the email? That way, it will only be sent on failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i add 1>/dev/null to every line, will my standard out be redirected?

Yes, to `/dev/null`. In effect, the STDOUT will be discarded and hence no mail will be sent for STDOUT.

> Will the behavior for standard error stay the same otherwise?

Yes; just to note, if you need to redirect STDERR, you need to use file descriptor 2, for example, redirecting to `/dev/null` (i.e. discarding the STDERR): `... 2>/dev/null`.